# how do i make things which appear after image recognition stay as it is? (unity3d vuforia)

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

Hello I'm developing a Vuforia AR image recognition app.

However, I wish to make an object appear upon scanning an image, and that image to stay unattached(not affected by the location of scanned image and has a fixed coordinate in the camera) to the image being recognized.

How can I make this happen ?

is this done through a script? if so, how can i script it ? and where will I add the script component ?

what I tried so far is

just followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfxqfdtxyVA)
but used a different target and object

and I just want to make the object that appears after recognition be unattached

thank you in advance.

Comment: and what else you tried so far.. ? can you please post your code ?

Comment: i only followed a video didnt do any coding because i dont know where to start

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still following this post.

Here is your answer :

How can I make this happen ?

> By transferring the 3D model to the camera.

is this done through a script?

> Yes.

if so, how can i script it ?

> First you need to know what kind of "Stick" you want. Is there a trigger button or it just stick when the camera moved away from the marker?
>
> If there's a trigger button, you can script it such when you click/tap at the button, it change the 3D's (GameObject) parent to the camera.
>
> ```
> my3D.transform.SetParent(Camera.main.transform);
> ```
>
> If you want to make it such that when you move your camera away, and
>   the 3D model automatically stick to camera, it will slightly more
>   complicated. You need to access to the
>   ImageTargetTrackableEventHandler.cs in the VuforiaImageTarget object.
>   Look for a function called OnTrackingLost(). Instead of :
>
> ```
>     Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
>     Collider[] colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
>
>     // Disable rendering:
>     foreach (Renderer component in rendererComponents)
>     {
>         component.enabled = false;
>     }
>
>     // Disable colliders:
>     foreach (Collider component in colliderComponents)
>     {
>         component.enabled = false;
>     }
> ```
>
> you remove the whole chunk of code by disable it, and on top of the
>   scripts add in
>
> ```
> [SerializeField]
> GameObject my3D;
> ```
>
> and inside the OnTrackingLost() function, put in this code :
>
> ```
> my3D.transform.SetParent(Camera.main.transform);
> ```
>
> After that, go to the Inspector view, click on the ImageTarget, there
>   will be something like this :
>
> [image]
>
> simply drag your 3D from the Hierarchy view to the variable image
>   shown.

and where will I add the script component ?

> if you're using the "button" method, simply create an empty gameobject
>   and attach the script to it.

Hope it helps, because there is very limited support out there for vuforia. :)

Answer (score 0):

the only thing that worked for me was adding a boolean variable at the begining of the script, and make it that when OnTrackingLost() enters, the boolean becomes true. I don't know if I explain myself.

First you create at the begining:

`private bool bol = false;`

Then on the function:

```cs
private void OnTrackingLost()
{

    Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
    Collider[] colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
    if (!bol) {
        // Disable rendering:
        foreach (Renderer component in rendererComponents)
        {
            component.enabled = false;
        }

        // Disable colliders:
        foreach (Collider component in colliderComponents)
        {
            component.enabled = false;
        }
        bol = true;
    }


    Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " lost");
}
```